# Vue reactivity on object graph containing cyclic references

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, tree, vue-reactivity

Some context first:

I am building a mineswheeper application based on VueJS.
My grid is an objects tree : Each Box object has a 'neighbors' property that contains Box objects that are the very next boxes.

The structure is circular, but is fine.

Now the problem:

First I tried on a small grid (5x5) It worked fine, but when trying generating a bigger grid (50x50) Vue spawned a 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error when setting up observers, here is the log
[image: Callstack error in console]

The tree seems too big for vue to handle reactivity.

It has been confirmed when freezing my object and it worked just fine (no callstack error):

```
data() {
    const game = new MinesWheeper(30, 30, 40)
    Object.freeze(game)
    return {
      game
    }
  }
```

But the reactivity is (obviously) down because of the freeze. Nevertheless I need reactivity to reveal boxes on click.

Now here is my questions/leads I found:

- Have you ever been facing this callstack problem with Vue or am I missing something ?
- Is there a way to make reactivity work on VueJS with a such object structure ? (Is VueX a part of the solution ? I don't really know it)
- Or should I think about use something else than VueJS ? (Do it in vanilla ??)

Thanks in advance,
sorry if my post is messy, it is my first post ever in 5 years, I am quite nervous lol

Edit : Here is what a game object looks like:

```
game: { // MinesWheeper
  _grid: { // Grid
    "_bombsNumber": 40
    _boxes: [ // Array of Box
      {
        "_hasBomb": true
        "_index": 0
        "_isRevealed": false
        "_neighbors": [Box, Box, Box, Box]
        "hasBomb": true
        "index": 0
        "isRevealed": false
        "nearBombs": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Moreover, on clicking on a Box, I need to either to:
- end game if Box.hasBomb is true
- show the content (if there is no bomb in it)
- or spread reveal() call if Box.nearBombs equals 0

my Box.reveal() method is recursive:

```
reveal() {
    if (this._isRevealed) return

    this._isRevealed = true

    if (this.hasBomb) {
      console.log('Game over')
    } else if (this.nearBombs === 0) {
      this._neighbors.forEach(neighbor => {
        neighbor.reveal()
      })
    }
  }
```

That's why I think I need reactivity though, to update the view at each Box.reveal calls

Comment: What is exact shape of your data structure ? Can you add it to your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have one dimensional array of Box objects and each object contains `neighbors` array with references (to the main array items) to its adjacent Boxes.

You can use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to create `neighbors` property with `configurable: false` and Vue won't be able to setup reactivity on it. But rest of the Box object properties remains reactive.

I'v setup a [little demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-reactivity-on-object-graph-containing-cyclic-references-jt9fd) myself. All important is in `components/HelloWorld.vue` component.

Example is little convoluted because with array its possible to reference "prev" and "next" element easily with index but I needed to introduce cyclic references between objects.

On my machine, it will throw an error with 10000 items in the array. But if you switch `this.setupRelatioships(boxes);` call with `this.setupRelatioshipsWithProperties(boxes);` error goes away.

```js
setupRelatioships(boxes) {
      for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].prev = i > 0 ? boxes[i - 1] : null;
        boxes[i].next = i < boxes.length - 1 ? boxes[i + 1] : null;
      }
    },
    setupRelatioshipsWithProperties(boxes) {
      const opts = {
        configurable: false,
        enumerable: true,
        writable: true
      };

      for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        Object.defineProperty(boxes[i], "prev", {
          ...opts,
          value: i > 0 ? boxes[i - 1] : null
        });
        Object.defineProperty(boxes[i], "next", {
          ...opts,
          value: i < boxes.length - 1 ? boxes[i + 1] : null
        });
      }
    },
```

---

Previously referenced [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Akryum/q8wu5aem/) (credits to [Guillaume Chau](https://jsfiddle.net/user/Akryum/fiddles/))

Comment: Thanks for answering, I tried it, but it seems that it reacts the same as Object.freeze(). I mean that view is not updated on Box.reveal() call. In the example you attached, I think I don't get how b and c refresh when clicking on a++ button

Comment: Regarding the example...clicking a++ button tells Vue to re-render whole template and it will of course use current values of `b` and `c` when that happens....

Comment: Hmm that's strange. `__neighbors` is just references to other boxes that are already in the main array, right ?

Comment: Oh ok, so I need to apply the logic of the 'a' button to the grid, I will explore this lead, because having to click a 'refresh' button each time user click on a Box may be a bit unpleasant. And you are absolutely right in your second comment: _neighbors is an array of references to existing Box objects

Comment: @Doltario You can take a look at my own demo - it solves the problem and objects remain reactive...

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Michal, I got some troubles only with my implementation of your solution, but it will work just fine, your demo is awesome. Problem solved !